# While using Jetty as a server, how do I return a clear json 401 error when JWT Filter blocks unauthenticated users in Spring security?

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, jetty, spring-filter

I have my Spring Security bean which is doing well in blocking unauthorised requests, while using Tomcat, the error response is a clean exception with the message but with Jetty, a `text/html` is returned even in postman as shown below.
[image]
And my `doFilterInternal` JWT Filter is as below.

```
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtility jwtUtility;

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = null;
        String userName = null;

        if(null != authorization && authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = authorization.substring(7);
            userName = jwtUtility.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        }

        if(null != userName && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails
                    = userService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            try {
                if (jwtUtility.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                            null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(
                            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest)
                    );

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
//                System.out.println("Hello world");
                Map<String, Object> errorDetails = new HashMap<>();
                errorDetails.put("ACCESS_DENIED", e.getMessage());
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
                httpServletResponse.setContentType(String.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                mapper.writeValue(httpServletResponse.getWriter(), errorDetails);
                return;
            }

        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

With Tomcat as my server, everything works as expected, but I have shifted to Jetty Server, how best can I replace this code below to work the same for Jetty?

```
Map<String, Object> errorDetails = new HashMap<>();
                errorDetails.put("ACCESS_DENIED", e.getMessage());
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
                httpServletResponse.setContentType(String.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                mapper.writeValue(httpServletResponse.getWriter(), errorDetails);
                return;
```

My expected response when the user has not sent in their jwt is as follows:-

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
{
    "ACCESS_DENIED": "Some error message here",
}
```

Otherwise, the request should go through therefore the filter should not return anything.

Note: **Please feel free to edit this question to make it better as I have more friends trying to solve the same issue.**

Comment: Why are you not using the built in JWT features of spring security? Writing custom security is bad practice

Comment: I get, but I wanted some minimal features that's why am using this mode, just focus on helping me @Toerktumlare, thanks in advance

Comment: I am helping you, im telling you to read the spring docs on how to implement the handling of JWTs in a secure manor. Im not going to help you do bad practices.

Comment: You realize am using Spring 2.6 which does not have the mentioned features!!

Comment: What are you talking about? Spring security has had support for handling JWT since 2018. You clearly havn’t read the docs

Comment: Please share where I can read, coz I navigated the docs and could not find it

Answer (score 1):

The response you are seeing is the default Servlet ERROR dispatch handling (see DispatcherType.ERROR)

Use the standard Servlet error-page mappings to specify your own custom mappings for handling errors.  A mapping can be based on status codes, throwables, and more (see Servlet descriptor and `<error-page>` mappings)

Comment: Please show me how, in the rest of the program, I have managed to override my responses, but on the filters, am still getting an issue, show me how to override this in the filter-level